# Saving and updating a .txt file in VB

Tags: vb.net

I wrote code to create a summary.txt file and to write some lines to it.

This is the code:

```
Dim FileToSaveAs As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs)

File.WriteLine("Date and time" & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
File.WriteLine(" ")
File.WriteLine("Client Number: " & " " & Clients)
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("Beginning of new order:")
File.WriteLine("")

For index = 0 To OrderListBox.Items.Count - 1
    File.WriteLine(OrderListBox.Items(index))
Next

File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("Price" & " " & "£" & " " & ZYZZ)
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("VAT" & " " & "£" & " " & VAT)
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("Total" & " " & "£" & " " & MAX)
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("______________________________________________________")
File.WriteLine("")
File.WriteLine("")
File.Close()

Clients = Clients + 1
```

This code basically will create and pop up a new save file dialog then the user decides where to save it which is perfectly how I want it. But whenever the user target this code again it will trigger the save file dialog again which is absolutely what I don't want it to do.

What I want it to do is to add the new lines to the same .txt file that was already saved

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and appending text to txt file in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613666/creating-and-appending-text-to-txt-file-in-vb-net)

Comment: Mind is different because he is not using Save Dialog. If the user Changed the file name while saving it the code will crash @fillobotto

Comment: See @Muhammad comment on his answer. based on what you asked, this is a duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs, True)
```

The `True` means that the new data will be append to the file, `False` to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Comment: It is working now fine but it still displays the save file dialog and when I overwrite it, it works. But still I have to over write first any solution? thanx

Comment: You said : **"What I want it to do is to add the new lines to the same .txt file that was already saved"**

So I posted my answer depending on your request.

Anyways, you didn't show us the full code, but I can suggest you to not show your dialog box SaveFileDialog1 in the second time you need to append data.

Comment: Yh how can i not show it again unless the file did not exist? Thanx @Muhammad

Comment: Call this : `SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` just one time to get the file name and store it in a variable to use it whenever you need without showing the SaveFileDialog again.

Comment: Hi, i tried it but it didnt work can you please demonstrate it. thank you

Comment: Not a full code of your entire project, just the part around this task.