# Using StringBuilder to Append Contents of a List Box to a Text File

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a programme in visual studio where, once you press a button, the contents of a `ListBox` are added to a text file.

I am currently using a `StringBuilder` to do this as my professor has told me this is the easiest and quickest way -I am aware I can use `StreamWriter` as well.

```
Dim CreateReciept As New System.Text.StringBuilder

CreateReciet.Append(lstOrderForm.Text & vbCrLf)

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", Text.ToString())

Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

This is my code as of now; however, when I run it, it produces a blank form rather than the contents of the list box.

Comment: Well, for one thing you are outputing the contents of the variable (or control I guess) Text, rather than your string builder (second parameter of line 3). Unless that had something in it then you would get a blank file as the result.

Comment: Also, a stringbuilder is used to build a string with multiple parts in an efficient way (simply appending to a string, is inefficient because each time you do so you are creating a new string object). In your code above you are only appending a single item, so it's not doing anything useful - might as well just use a string, or inline the value

Comment: Thanks Kevin, why am I getting a blank file? I'm going to switch to use StreamWriter, but why am I getting a blank text file?

Comment: What is Text in the third line? It's certainly not your stringbuilder. Replace it with CreateReciet.ToString() and see if you get something better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613727/1383168

Comment: Just to clarify what Dave and DaveRules have said. The spelling has nothing to do with the issue you are having. I've rolled back your edit (or at least it's pending, could be rejected) as your edit created another issue (introduced a bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong thing. [ListBox.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) will only provide the text of the currently selected item:

> When the value of this property is set to a string value, the ListBox searches for the item within the ListBox that matches the specified text and selects the item. You can also use this property to determine which items are currently selected in the ListBox. If the SelectionMode property of the ListBox is set to **SelectionMode.MultiExtended**, this property returns the text of the first selected item. If the SelectionMode property of the ListBox is not set to **SelectionMode.None**, this property returns the text of the first selected item.

Instead loop through the [ListBox.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

> This property enables you to obtain a reference to the list of items that are currently stored in the ListBox. With this reference, you can add items, remove items, and obtain a count of the items in the collection. For more information about the tasks that can be performed with the item collection, see the ListBox.ObjectCollection class reference topics.

Lastly don't use `Text.ToString`, that won't work. Instead use your `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For Each item In lstOrderForm.Items
    sb.Append(item.ToString() & vbCrLf)
Next

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", sb.ToString())

Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

The code produces the following output for me:

[image]

Comment: Without an absolute path the file will be created in the applications current directory, which is likely to be where the EXE lives if nothing else has changed it. This will still work for what the user is trying to achieve, as all he's doing is firing it up in its own process to view it. It's a bit untidy though, for sure

Comment: @KevinO'Donovan thanks for that, you're right. The issue will be likely linked to not looping through the items and not using the `StringBuilder` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
Dim CreateReciet As New System.Text.StringBuilder

CreateReciet.Append(lstOrderForm.Text & vbCrLf)

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", CreateReciet.ToString())

Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

As I said above though, your stringbuilder isn't doing anything useful, so you could just write:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", lstOrderForm.Text & vbCrLf)
Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

Comment: I don't use the native listbox very often, so I'm not sure whether the Text property does what you want. If you're still not getting what you're expecting at this point, you may need to loop through the list box's items and append each one. If you were doing that then your stringbuilder would make sense

Comment: I've just checked the ListBox documentation and ListBox.Text will definitely not do what you want it to do - "Gets or searches for the text of the currently selected item in the ListBox.". It only returns the text of one item at most. So you will need to loop through the items. Look at Jinx88909's answer for details. Doubtless this is why your professor suggested using a listbox!

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've just provided the links to the documentation myself, hadn't realised you had made the comment regarding the `ListBox.Text`. Funny one really as I've never used the `ListBox.Text` property and instead leaned towards `ListBox.SelectedItem`.