# How to append to the file

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, io

I coded this code to save my password generated to a file. I cannot append this file. It just prompts me to save a new file. When i click generate a second time I want to append the file the password will be saved in, when asked to generate password with a comma or a break in the file.

I am a newbie with VB.Net!!!!

```
    Using dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "Save"
        dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Html File (*.html)| *.Html|Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg.CheckPathExists = True
        dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        dlg.DefaultExt = "txt"
        Dim myReturn As DialogResult = dlg.ShowDialog()

        If System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK.Equals(myReturn) Then
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Using
```

Comment: Well none of your code is VBScript, so what are you using? The syntax looks more like VB.Net to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and appending text to txt file in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613666/creating-and-appending-text-to-txt-file-in-vb-net)

Comment: @Icemanind as stated [in the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613735/692942).

Answer (score 0):

First check permission.  Did you run as administrator when you opened it? Right-finger-click /run as administrator...

Then check folder permissions.  /properties/security/

Answer (score 0):

`WriteAllText` will not append to the file. You have to use `AppendAllText`, to append to the file.
Also make sure, file is not in edit mode i.e. opened/locked by other program.
Try below code, it will show error message if it fails to append. The error message will help you to localize the problem and you can try to solve it.

```
Try
    Using dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "Save"
        dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Html File (*.html)| *.Html|Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg.CheckPathExists = True
        dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        dlg.DefaultExt = "txt"

        If dlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dlg.FileName, TextBox1.Text)
        End If

    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Really? Marked this as a duplicate but still people ignore it and post [answers that have already been given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613735/692942).

Comment: its asking me to save a new file again when i click my generate button and when i click on th one i already created in the first place it wants to overwrite it i just want it to ask one time per session?