# Create a text file with a variable name and write to it

Tags: vb.net

For an application i'm working on, i am trying to create a 'save data' feature.

First off, it needs to create a `.txt` file with a custom name, this needs to be the date (today) and the text of a textbox, it needs to be in the format of `yyyymmdd_textbox1(.txt)`

How would i go about doing this? it can create it where ever, but if it already exists it needs to append to it on a new line

thanks for any responses

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613666/creating-and-appending-text-to-txt-file-in-vb-net and many other questions on here. Did you search before posting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file - internet saerch engines are your friends

Answer (score 3):

If you want a file-name from user-input you first need this method:

```
Public Function SanitizeFileName(fileName as String) As String  
    For Each c In IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
        filename = filename.Replace(c, "_"c)
    Next
    Return fileName
End Function
```

Then it's easy

```
Dim filename = $"{DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}_{SanitizeFileName(textbox1.Text)}.txt"
```