# how to write text from TextBox to a new line in existing .txt located on c:\words.txt in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to the programming and I'm trying to accomplish this:
how to write text from TextBox to a new line in existing .txt located on c:\words.txt in Visual Basic

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have a lock at [Creating and appending text to txt file in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613666/creating-and-appending-text-to-txt-file-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can meet your requirement without a stream too.

Firstest of all, declare your `fName` which contains a file name as string.

Then use the following code in your `Button.Click` event:

```
File.AppendAllText(fName, TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine)
```

If the file doesn't exists, the `AppendAllText` method will automatically create a new file and writes all the data containing in `TextBox1` along with a new-line as per of your requirement.

[image: File Writer and Appender]

Hope it helps you.